# How to Start Video Recording in Android TV

Tags: android-tv

I would like to implement video recording in Android TV.I could not find any RecordAction or RecordButton, or any other event that notifies the android system to call onCreateRecordigSession.

What I would need is an event which triggers android system to start recording.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Recording a Session](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/content-recording.html) docs:

> After your TV input service registers that it supports recording
>   functionality, the system calls your
>   TvInputService.onCreateRecordingSession() method when it needs to
>   access your app's recording implementation. Implement your own
>   TvInputService.RecordingSession subclass and return it when the
>   onCreateRecordingSession() callback fires. This subclass is
>   responsible for switching to the correct channel data, recording the
>   requested data, and communicating recording status and errors to the
>   system.
>
> When the system calls RecordingSession.onTune(), passing in a channel
>   URI, tune to the channel that the URI specifies. Notify the system
>   that your app has tuned to the desired channel by calling
>   notifyTuned() or, if your app could not tune to the proper channel,
>   call notifyError().
>
> The system next invokes the RecordingSession.onStartRecording()
>   callback. Your app must start recording immediately. When the system
>   invokes this callback, it may provide a URI that contains information
>   about the program that is about to be recorded. When the recording is
>   done, you'll copy this data to the RecordedPrograms data table.
>
> Finally, the system calls RecordingSession.onStopRecording(). At this
>   point, your app must stop recording immediately. You also need to
>   create an entry in the RecordedPrograms table. This entry should
>   include the recorded session data URI in the
>   RecordedPrograms.COLUMN_RECORDING_DATA_URI column, and any program
>   information that the system provided in the initial call to
>   onStartRecording().
>
> For more details on how to access the RecordedPrograms table see
>   [Managing Recorded
>   Sessions](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/content-recording.html#sessions).